# Support all android screen size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, design-patterns

I'm have tired to support all android , but I want to ask about supporting all screen size on android

I have 4 layout folders :

```
layout
layout-ldpi  2.7 inch = 240*320 
layout-mdpi  3.2 = 320*480
layout-hdpi  3.7 = 480*800 
layout-xhdpi 800*1280 
layout-xxhdpi 5 inch 1080*1920
```

Is this setting in each layout support all devices or maybe I have missed some thing ?

Note : I have reviewed android site Android Developers many time .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You should split your resoures in two groups. One with density (folder called drawable) which contains images in different sizes for different display resolutions. The second one with layout (called layout) is for supporting different UI layout of each screen. Typically for tablet or mobile phones. So you should have forlder

- drawable-ldpi, mdpi, etc. - here will be your png files
- layout-"default",sw360, sw600, sw720 ("large" mobile, small 7" tablet, large 10" tablet). If your are targeting below 3.2, you can't you sw (smallest-width) but use older small, medium, large, xlarge screen size. - here will be your *.xml layout files
  Don't mix up layout and density resource qualifiers together. [See more here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I named it : layout-ldpi , and drawable-ldpi is this ok ? or should name it x-larage

Comment: Layout directory is typically used ONLY with screen size qualifier  - different layout for mobile and tablet UI. If you are targeting 3.2+ you can use smallest-width (sw360). If not you should use layout-small, xlarge etc. On the other hand you are using folder drawable ONLY with density qualifier (ldpi, mdpi, etc.). So drawable-ldip is correct, but layout-ldpi not.